# TypeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.Binary' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need your help, I'm trying to insert files (.txt) to postgres using psycopg2 with python, but sends this error and don't understand...

error:

```
TypeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.Binary' object does not support indexing
```

I have:

```
archivo=open("coordenada.out",'rb').read()

cur.execute("insert into fhi(coordenadas) values(%s)",(psycopg2.Binary(archivo)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
(psycopg2.Binary(archivo),)
```

It expects an iterable. The comma will make it a tuple. Otherwise it will try to iterate over the `Binary`