# SQL problem in python prepared statement: 'int' object does not support indexing error

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, tkinter, prepared-statement

```
def updateattendance(labels):
    updatequery='update students set id= id + 1 where rno= %s'
    for label in labels:
        tuplee=(label)
        curr.execute(updatequery,tuplee)
```

the last line i.e. curr.execute(updatequery,tuplee) gives a error of 'int' object does not support indexing.
however the sql query in itself doesnot show any error.
the label in the code is a integer number.
Attaching a screenshot for reference.
Thanks.[image: The image shows the errors that pop up on the execution of the last line.]

Comment: Should be `tuplee=(label,)`

Comment: @acw1668 well thanks and it did solve the problem but can you please clarify. Thanks

Comment: As argument for `execute()` expects tuple.  `(label)` is not a tuple, but `(label,)` is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'psycopg2.\_psycopg.Binary' object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175340/typeerror-psycopg2-psycopg-binary-object-does-not-support-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

Since the ***label*** in the code is a **integer number**. So
try this out.

```
def updateattendance(labels):
updatequery='update students set id= id + 1 where rno= %s'
    for label in labels:
        tuplee=(label)
        cr.execute(updatequery,str(tuplee)) #Convert to String
        con.commit()
```

Hopefully the error "**'int' object does not support indexing error**" will be eliminated.